# StackDriver Uptime Check with Maintenance Window

Tags: stackdriver

Is there a way to set a maintenance window on Stackdriver alerting for a time period where I know the site goes down for maintenance (nightly backups), so that it doesn't fire alerts during that timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

currently, there isn't a way to automatically suppress policies from triggering during certain times. You could filter out notifications during that time period if you're aware of maintenance windows. We are looking into this and thinking about potential functionality in this area.
Thanks for using Stackdriver!
Amir.